# How do I fix "Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 536870912 bytes. The amount of memory may be low"

Tags: vb.net, wcf, crystal-reports, windows-services

I have a Windows Service application that calls a WCF. That WCF uses Crystal Reports to create a report and return the content to the Service Application. This all works fine unless I have a very large report. Then it fails with this message "Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 536870912 bytes. The amount of memory may be low.

I goggled this problem and it appeared several times but none of the hints seem to help me.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Bob

Comment: Start by making sure that the WCF application is running as a 64-bit process.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is being done by I am not sure how to set or check this. Thanks.